# Finding a basis satisfying a property of an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, call those $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ respectively. I want to find a basis for this space relative to which the inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Tr}\: (XY)$ has matrix $n=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$. I don't see how it is at all possible, matrix of an inner product relative to the basis will look like
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \langle Y_1, Y_1 \rangle & \langle Y_1, Y_2 \rangle& \langle Y_1, Y_3 \rangle \\ \langle Y_2, Y_1 \rangle & \langle Y_2, Y_2 \rangle & \langle Y_2, Y_3 \rangle \\ \langle Y_3, Y_1 \rangle & \langle Y_3, Y_2 \rangle & \langle Y_3, Y_3 \rangle \end{pmatrix}
$$
which implies that $\langle Y_3,Y_3\rangle=-1$, but the inner product is always nonnegative, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element of your vector space $V$ has the form
$$
a Y_1 + b Y_2 + c Y_3 =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b + c i\\
-b + c i & -a
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & z\\
- \bar z & -a
\end{bmatrix},
$$
with $a,b,c $ real, and $z = b + c i$.

Write $z_k = b_k + c_k i$, for $k = 1, 2$. Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & z_1\\
- \bar z_1 & -a_1
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 & z_2\\
- \bar z_2 & -a_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 a_2 -z_1 \bar z_2 & \dots\\
\dots & a_1 a_2 - \bar z_1 z_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
whose half-trace is $$a_1 a_2 - b_1 b_2 - c_1 c_2.$$

But then [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) should tell you that since you get in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
with respect to the given basis, then you cannot get it in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Yes, that would be my next step, but my question is whether it's valid at all to define an inner product as half-trace of matrix product.

Comment: @JimmyR, you're right, an *inner product* is required to be positive-definite. The object here would be a nondegenerate, symmetric, *bilinear form*